# Blazor WebAssembly Lifecycle Methods when accidentally Browser refreshes

Tags: c#, telerik, blazor-webassembly

i am getting used to Blazor WASM.
I am having some Pages which are inheriting from a custom base class.
In this base class i have a cascading parameter.

```
 public class CustomBlazorComponentBase : LayoutComponentBase
    {
        private bool disposedValue;

        [Inject]
        protected HttpInterceptorService Interceptor { get; set; }

        [CascadingParameter]
        protected TelerikNotification Notification { get; set; }

        protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            Interceptor.RegisterEvent(Notification.ShowError);

            return base.OnInitializedAsync();
        }   
}
```

In the MainLayout.razor ive got the following lines

```
<CascadingValue IsFixed="true" Value="@Notification">
                <div class="content px-4">
                    @Body
                </div>
</CascadingValue>            
<TelerikNotification @ref="@Notification" Class="notification"
                                 HorizontalPosition="@NotificationHorizontalPosition.Center"
                                 VerticalPosition="@NotificationVerticalPosition.Bottom" />
```

The Page starts

```
@inherits ItnBlazorComponentBase
```

The HttpInterceptor-Class gets a delegate to show a Error if something wents wrong.
Everything is working fine and as expected.

BUT when the User accidentally hitting F5 of the browser to refresh the page no Lifecycle-Method gets called. Not OnInitializedAsync, not OnParametersSetAsync and so on.

Why? And how to avoid that problem?
The problem is, there will be no registration of my delegate and so no Notification is shown.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own Question after couple of hours of research. Its quite simple and answered in this question from Stackoverflow

[Outermost CascadingValue is lost on page refresh or direct link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63944166/outermost-cascadingvalue-is-lost-on-page-refresh-or-direct-link)

The Solution was to surround the CascadingParameter in MainLayout.razor with a boolean

```
        @if (HasRendered)
        {
            <CascadingValue IsFixed="true" Value="@Notification">
                <div class="content px-4">
                    @Body
                </div>
            </CascadingValue>
        }
```

And in the Code Behind MainLayout.razor.cs set it after first Rendering

```
    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if(firstRender)
        {
            HasRendered = true;
            StateHasChanged();
        }

        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I applied your solution but still the issue not resolved, when refresh the page cascading parameter lost
@if (HasRendered)
{

@Body

```
        }
```

Then I defined the bool variable HasRendered and pasted the below code to the MainLayout.razor.cs
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
if (firstRender)
{
HasRendered = true;
StateHasChanged();
}

```
    base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).