# Calling StateHasChanged() on parent component from child component

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

In my blazor app for administrating cases, I have a property `ClaimedBy` on an instance of a class `CaseDetails.cs` which holds the username of the administrator who has claimed the case.

It is displayed like this on the index page:
`<p>Claimed by: @caseDetails.ClaimedBy</p>`

Now, from a child component, I'm trying to update the value of `ClaimedBy` like this:
`caseDetails.ClaimedBy = newUser;`

But the name on the index page (the parent component), is not updated automatically. It updates correctly if I make a button on the index page with a method that calls `StateHasChanged()` like this:

```
<button @onclick="UpdatePage">update page</button>

@code {
    private void UpdatePage()
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

I have tried to call `StateHasChanged()` from my child component, in the same method which sets the new value of the `ClaimedBy` property, but that doesn't work. `StateHasChanged()` has to be called from the parent component. How do I get it to update automatically once the new value has been set?

Comment: It's better to use EventCallBack parameter to pass a value from the child to the parent component and then call await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but how would I use event callback?

Comment: I implemented your desire code by EventCallBack in the answer, I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented your code by EventCallBack and it works correctly:

Parent:

```
@page "/parent"
@using CheckStateHasChanged.Class
@inject CaseDetails caseDetails
<h3>Parent</h3>
<p>Claimed by: @caseDetails.ClaimedBy</p>
<Child caseDetailClaimedBy="UpdatePage"></Child>

@code {

    string claimedByInParent = string.Empty;

    public async Task UpdatePage(string claimedByFromChild)
    {
        claimedByInParent = claimedByFromChild;
    }
}
```

Child:

```
@using CheckStateHasChanged.Class
@inject CaseDetails caseDetails
<h3>Child</h3>
<button @onclick="(()=>UpdatePage(caseDetails.ClaimedBy))"></button>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> caseDetailClaimedBy { get; set; }

    public async Task UpdatePage(string claimedBy)
    {
        caseDetails.ClaimedBy = "test";
        await caseDetailClaimedBy.InvokeAsync(claimedBy);
    }
}
```

CaseDetails.cs

```
namespace CheckStateHasChanged.Class
{
    public class CaseDetails
    {
        public string ClaimedBy { get; set; } = "admin";
    }
}
```

For more info about `EventCallBack` you can refer to [Component events](https://blazor-university.com/components/component-events/) and [5-steps-to-implement-event-call-backs-in-blazor](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/5-steps-to-implement-event-call-backs-in-blazor/)

Comment: EventCallbacks are one way to do it, but can this be done via data-binding? A lot of things update automagically when a parameter/property is updated. I have, for example, many places where on a parent page, I do like `@if (_myPoco.IsSomeBoolTrue) { update UI }` and all I need to do, is to update theIsSomeBoolTrue, and the UI changes with it. But, I tried the same approach in a Component, where the Parameter is assigned from the Component itself, but in this case, Parent does not update automatically.

Comment: I think the another way that you can do it is `shared service`. For more info, please refer to this question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55775060/blazor-component-refresh-parent-when-model-is-updated-from-child-component